# Google Plus Domains API AccessTokenRefreshError

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-apps, google-api-python-client, google-admin-sdk

I'm attempting to use the Google+ Domains API to provision circles for my Google Apps domain. I'm using domain-wide delegation as per https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation which I have already used successfully for group, user and calendar provisioning. In the API console, I've added the Google+ API and Google+ Domains API to the API project. I've tried using both the pre-existing key, and generating a new one. When I attempt to run the following code:

```
service_account_email='somelongstring@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
key=file("path/to/keyfile","rb").read()
user_email='someroleaccount@mydomain.com'
SCOPES_PLUS = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.stream.write',
]
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(service_account_email, key,
                                            scope=SCOPES_PLUS, sub=user_email)
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
plus = build(serviceName='plus', version='v1domains', http=http)
```

I get

```
AccessTokenRefreshError: access_denied
```

when it hits the build() call.

However, the exact same code (with different scopes and services) works for the directory service, groupssettings service and calendar service.

I have tried with both a role account as the sub email address, and as my own (super-admin) account.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you remember to give the service account authorization for the new scopes in the Control Panel for the domain? The process [is described in the Drive documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account). Be sure to enter the Google Plus Domains scopes as well as the Directory and Group Settings scopes as any changes overwrite your existing authorizations.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a tutorial to use the new G+ Domains APIs on Google App Engine with Python, it explains each necessary configuration step by step and provides some example code:

https://gist.github.com/vircheck/6292176

also, don't forget the official quick start [here](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/quickstart/python) but remember that this one does not work on App Engine.